# gremlin-python - How can I avoid "Unclosed Client Session" when exiting my program?

Tags: python, gremlin

**Problem**

I have followed the simple example provided in `gremlin-python` instructions and did run:

```
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g'))
```

But then my `main` closed I get the following error message:

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x00000134D79FB070>
```

How can I avoid getting this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Solution*

The `close` method is in the object returned by `DriverRemoteConnection()`. Obtain the
object to `DriverRemoteConnection()` and then perform the `close` operation when you are
ready to close it.

```
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

connection = DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g')
g = traversal().withRemote(connection)
connection.close()
```